# How to get text without html tag selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

[Need to get text 6537](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2yXA.png)

Tried many xpaths:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Client ID')]")).getText()
```

It just gives text Master Client Id not 6537.

if we change xpath to `//b[contains(text(),'Client ID')]/text()`

Then selenium gives error as below

```
The result of the xpath expression "//b[contains(text(),'Client ID')]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on the screenshot** it seems like the text you are trying to capture is not part of the  tag. It is the text of the parent element.

[image]

What you need to do is to have get the text of the entire parent div and use a regex to extract the number out.

```
String parentText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Client ID')]")).getText()
// find and remove any non digit characters
String number = parentText.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Comment: Thanks. The only way to get that text was by getting its parent text first.